# jQuery Mobile swipe event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a `<div>` tag and when user swipes over it then it logs `swipe`. There are three swipes i.e. `swipe`, `swipeleft` and `swiperight` in jQuery Mobile but I want to use `swipe` only. What I want to find out is when user swipe over `<div>` tag then log either `swipeleft` or `swiperight` based on user's swipe direction. Is it possible? If yes then how?

```
$('.image').on('swipe', function (e) {
    console.log('swipe);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To log a swipe left use

```
    $('.image').on('swipeleft', function (e) {
       console.log('swipeleft');
    });
```

for right

```
    $('.image').on('swiperight', function (e) {
       console.log('swiperight');
    });
```

place this in the function `$(document).on('pageinit', function() {}` of your code.

These events can be extended, this is the default for these events

$.event.special.swipe.handleSwipe :

```
function( start, stop ) {
    if ( stop.time - start.time < $.event.special.swipe.durationThreshold &&
        Math.abs( start.coords[ 0 ] - stop.coords[ 0 ] ) > $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold &&
        Math.abs( start.coords[ 1 ] - stop.coords[ 1 ] ) < $.event.special.swipe.verticalDistanceThreshold ) {

        start.origin.trigger( "swipe" )
            .trigger( start.coords[0] > stop.coords[ 0 ] ? "swipeleft" : "swiperight" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? are you looking to extend the default events?

Comment: can you give an example of how to extend the handleswipe event and get the direction without using `swipeleft` and `swiperight`?