# .animate({ 'marginLeft' : }) woking as zoom-in and zoom-out

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have an image in the screen, which covers 80% of the screen.

I want to move it left and right on swipe of the button. i am trying to do it like this

```
$("#movebtn").swiperight(function() {
        $('#moveimage').animate({
           'marginLeft' : "+=2px"
                    });
                });

            $("#movebtn").swipeleft(function() {
        $('#moveimage').animate({
           'marginLeft' : "-=2px"
                    });
                });
```

But when i swipe on a button instead of moving left/right image is zooming in and out. 
What's the mistake i am doing?

Thanks:)

Comment: check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131237/jquery-mobile-swipe-event

Answer (score 0):

try using margin-left instead of marginLeft